# Programmatically draw SVG icon with specific azimuth?

Tags: svg, drawing, draw

We currently have a leaflets map that plots several points. The service (consumed by the map) includes, among other things, the coordinates and the path for a static *svg* icon. That's working fine.

The next step is to create the actual icon so it looks like the icon below. In this example, there are 3 "groups" with 4 "lines" each. Each "line" has its own *azimuth* (the angle). Also, each "line" has its own length. The angle is the same any way you look at it, but the length is in miles, since this icon will be used in a map.

I don't even know where to begin. How does one create these icons?  In theory, the icons would be created and saved before they're plotted on the map. Are there libraries that do this?

[image]

Comment: Your title mentions "dynamically", but your question doesn't elaborate.  Do you need to create and/or update this icon at run time, where the angles and line lengths change each time?

Comment: You’re right. I’ll edit. It’s not dynamic.

Comment: Have you tried an editor like Inkscape? It is designed specifically for creating SVGs.

Comment: It would be programatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is pretty simple to create SVGs with Javascript. There are numerous examples of how to do that on this site, and elsewhere on the web.

For example:

```js
let svg = document.getElementById("icon");

// Add a "line" to the SVG, with a given azimuth, radius and length
function makeLine(azimuth, radius, length)
{
  let circumference = radius * 2 * Math.PI;
  // Create an SVG <circle> element
  let line = document.createElementNS(svg.namespaceURI, "circle");
  line.setAttribute("r", radius);
  line.setAttribute("stroke-dasharray", length + ' ' + circumference);
  line.setAttribute("transform", "rotate(" + azimuth + ")");
  // Add it to the <svg> element
  svg.appendChild(line);
}

let LEVEL1 = 93,
    LEVEL2 = 65,
    LEVEL3 = 37,
    LEVEL4 = 9;

makeLine(0,   LEVEL4, 15);
makeLine(120, LEVEL4, 15);
makeLine(240, LEVEL4, 15);

makeLine(310, LEVEL3, 50);
makeLine(180, LEVEL3, 55);

makeLine(290, LEVEL2, 95);

makeLine(300, LEVEL1, 110);
```

```css
svg {
  width: 400px;
}

circle {
  fill: none;
  stroke: black;
  stroke-width: 14;
}
```

```html
<svg id="icon" viewBox="-100 -100 200 200">
</svg>
```