# Call javascript function from Windows environment to generate myfile.svg?

Tags: javascript, c#, visual-studio, winforms, batch-file

With help from [Programmatically draw SVG icon with specific azimuth?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64706358/programmatically-draw-svg-icon-with-specific-azimuth/64724584#64724584), I have this javascript snippet that draws an *SVG* in my HTML page. It works great.

Instead of HTML, can this javascript function be used in a Windows environment (maybe a batch or WinForm) to create an actual *SVG* file that can be saved in a folder?

From a winform, for example, I would execute the javascript that will create the *SVG* and save it as *myFile.svg* in a physical path.

```js
let svg = document.getElementById("icon");

// Add a "line" to the SVG, with a given azimuth, radius and length
function makeLine(azimuth, radius, length)
{
  let circumference = radius * 2 * Math.PI;
  // Create an SVG <circle> element
  let line = document.createElementNS(svg.namespaceURI, "circle");
  line.setAttribute("r", radius);
  line.setAttribute("stroke-dasharray", length + ' ' + circumference);
  line.setAttribute("transform", "rotate(" + azimuth + ")");
  // Add it to the <svg> element
  svg.appendChild(line);
}

let LEVEL1 = 93;

makeLine(300, LEVEL1, 110);
```

```css
svg {
  width: 100px;
}

circle {
  fill: none;
  stroke: black;
  stroke-width: 16;
}
```

```html
<svg id="icon" viewBox="-100 -100 200 200">
</svg>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a Windows Form project add a `WebBrowser` component to your form, then you can run `javascript` like the following:

```
  private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        webBrowser1.DocumentText =
            "<html><head><script>" +
            @"function makeLine(azimuth, radius, length)
                {
                  var svg = document.getElementById('icon');
                  let circumference = radius * 2 * Math.PI;
                  
                  let line = document.createElementNS(svg.namespaceURI, 'circle');
                  line.setAttribute('r', radius);
                  line.setAttribute('stroke-dasharray', length + ' ' + circumference);
                  line.setAttribute('transform', 'rotate(' + azimuth + ')');
                  svg.appendChild(line);
                  return svg.outterHtml; //Note: this return line should be added to your code 
                }"
            + "</script></head><body><svg id=\"icon\" viewBox=\"-100 -100 200 200\"></svg></body></html>";
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var result = webBrowser1.Document.InvokeScript("makeLine", new object[] { 300, 93, 110 });
        var svg = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" ?><!DOCTYPE svg  PUBLIC '-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN'  'http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd'>";
        File.WriteAllText("C:\\a.svg", svg + result.ToString());
    }
```

Comment: The question is how to use the javascript function above to create a actual svg file.

Comment: Thank you for your help.